# UPDATE MySQL table that contains comma (,) in the field

Tags: php, mysql, replace

Imported into a MySQL table is a report that contains a user generated field value.

Possible field values include:

- PREFIX,1234
- PREFIX1234
- PREFIX_1234

All the example values represent the same thing but are typed in differently (I don't control the input system).

I would like to have all the values use this format:

- PREFIX_1234

I was trying to run this PHP query against the database to fix the comma values:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableA
SET unit_number = replace(unit_number,'FRGN,','FRGN_')
WHERE unit_number like 'FRGN,%'";
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Do I need to escape the comma in the query in order for it to work?

Comment: that should work fine, but what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Do you really want trailer_number in the WHERE clause, or unit_number?

Comment: you have referenced unit_number and trailer_number... shouldn't you be referencing the same field?

Comment: fixed the difference between 'unit_number' and 'trailer_number' -> didn't make my query example consistent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableA
SET unit_number = concat('FRGN_', replace(replace(replace(unit_number,'FRGN,','') ,'FRGN_',''), 'FRGN', ''))";
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableA
SET unit_number = concat('FRGN_', replace(replace(text,'FRGN,','') ,'FRGN',''))
WHERE unit_number NOT LIKE 'FRGN\_%'";
```